# How to know the function form from this representation

Tags: complex-analysis

Can you please help me to understand why if $\frac{1}{\big(1 - \overline{\lambda}f(z)\big)^n} = \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{c_r}{\big(1 - \overline{\lambda}z\big)^r}$ , then $f(z)$ is of the form $f(z) = a + bz$, a,b are complex numbers? Where $f(z)$ analytic and mapping the unit disk into itself, and $\lambda \in \mathbb{D} - \{0\}.$ I tried to expand the right side: $\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{c_r}{\big( 1 - \overline{\lambda}z \big)^r} = \frac{c_1}{1 - \overline{\lambda}z } + \frac{c_2}{\big( 1 - \overline{\lambda}z  \big)^2} + \frac{c_3}{\big( 1 - \overline{\lambda}z \big)^3}  + .... + \frac{c_n}{\big(1 - \overline{\lambda}z \big)^n}= \frac{c_1 (1 - \overline{\lambda}z )^{n-1} + c_2 (1 - \overline{\lambda}z )^{n-2} + .... + c_n }{\big(1 - \overline{\lambda}z \big)^n}$, then you mean that $\frac{\big(1 - \overline{\lambda}z\big)^n}{\big(1 - \overline{\lambda}f(z)\big)^n} = \Bigg( c_1 (1 - \overline{\lambda}z )^{n-1} + c_2 (1 - \overline{\lambda}z )^{n-2} + .... + c_n \Bigg)  $

$\implies \Bigg( c_1 (1 - \overline{\lambda}z )^{n-1} + c_2 (1 - \overline{\lambda}z )^{n-2} + .... + c_n \Bigg) =\Bigg( \frac{1 - \overline{\lambda}z}{1 - \overline{\lambda}f(z)}\Bigg)^n$.

$\implies  c_1 (1 - \overline{\lambda}z )^{n-1} + c_2 (1 - \overline{\lambda}z )^{n-2} + .... + c_n = \Bigg( 1 - \frac{\overline{\lambda} f(z) - \overline{\lambda} z}{1 - \overline{\lambda} f(z)} \Bigg)^n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n}{k}\Bigg(\frac{\overline{\lambda} f(z) - \overline{\lambda} z}{1 - \overline{\lambda} f(z)}\Bigg)^k$

$\implies 1 - \overline{\lambda} z = \frac{\overline{\lambda} f(z) - \overline{\lambda} z}{1 - \overline{\lambda} f(z)} \implies 1 - \overline{\lambda} f(z) - \overline{\lambda}z + \overline{\lambda}^2 z f(z) = \overline{\lambda}f(z) - \overline{\lambda} z$

$\implies f(z) = \frac{1}{2\overline{\lambda} - z \overline{\lambda}^2}$ !!! Can you help me, please??

Comment: Possible hint: expand the left size as a power series (perhaps in 1/z) and compare

Comment: note that $(\frac{1-\bar \lambda z}{1-\bar \lambda f(z)})^n$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ etc

Comment: I think that's the expansion of the right side, not the left side? Also, since you're the OP, put any additional work directly into your question, not as a comment

Comment: @Conrad The OP is trying to show f(z) is linear, but doesn't know it in advance. In theory, f(z) could be an arbitrarily high degree polynomial or even an arbitrary function

Comment: The trick would be to expand the left side and then match coefficients

Comment: @Barry the point is that if $g$ is a meromorphic function, then $g^n$ is also meromorphic but also at least $n:1$ in a specific way, so it being a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ (which follows if we multiply both sides by $(1-\bar \lambda z)^n$ has some specific consequences etc

Comment: @Conrad Oh, you're saying the right side must be a polynomial of degree n or less, therefore the left side must be too?

Comment: @Barry yes and then it is also an $n$th power etc (note that actually, RHS is a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ since the summation starts at $r=1$ so when you multiply by $(1-\bar \lambda z)^n$ all the terms have degree at most $n-1$)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138534/discussion-between-barry-carter-and-conrad).

Comment: @Conrad Is it true?? Where I failed??

Comment: your deduction $\Bigg( c_1 (1 - \overline{\lambda}z )^{n-1} + c_2 (1 - \overline{\lambda}z )^{n-2} + .... + c_n \Bigg) =\Bigg( \frac{1 - \overline{\lambda}z}{1 - \overline{\lambda}f(z)}\Bigg)^n$ is fine but from there you go on the wrong tangent; what you have to notice that RHS is an at least $n$ valent function (if not constant), while LHS is at most $n-1$ valent, so we must have that LHS=RHS=constant etc - for example if the zero of the RHS numerator is not cancelled by the denominator, it is a degree $n$ zero, while LHS can have only a zero of degree at most $n-1$ etc

Comment: similarly, if LHS is then not constant, it must have  a zero but then after canceling the numerator as above we get that RHS is $1/g^n$ so cannot have a zero (unless we allow $g$ hence $f$ to have a pole, but then the zero is again of degree at least $n$ so we come back to same contradiction); these two observations are enough to finsih directly

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for your reply.